# How to make ui-mask retain the invalid input when focus is lost?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I'm very new to ui-mask module in AngularJS UI. 
When I use it, I noticed that if the user enters an invalid format, and moved the focus to another control,the input will be cleared.

How to make ui-mask retain the invalid input when focus is lost? 
I want to show an error tooltip like 'this field is invalid' to users rather than clearing their input.

===============================

Update:

Thanks to majorlazer.

The ? mark works, for example, when the mask is ?99/9999, the input will not be cleared.

But there is a small problem about the place holder.
My mask is ?99/9999, and my place holder is

```
'__/____' (2 underscores and a slash and 4 underscores)
```

But when the input does not have focus, it shows

```
'_//____' (1 underscore and two slashes and 4 underscores)
```

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a potential solution from another posting here, but it was for jquery. Try adding a question mark in front of the mask, making it optional like ui-mask('?999-999-9999'). Note that it keeps the mask and the value when you leave focus, but won't validated.

Comment: Thanks! the ? mark works! I have a little problem about the place holder. Please see my update in the question.

Comment: Wow. great catch... That helped a lot.